# Gettext php doesnt translate all strings

Tags: php, gettext

Another `gettext` problem here.

`Gettext` works, and everything is seemingly set up correctly. However, I am now faced with the problem that some strings are not being translated on the website, despite being translated in the `.po` files. Gettext for some reason is ignoring some of the strings...

I find this behavior very strange. Could someone please help me here?

---

**Update:**

So... I somewhat fixed my problem, but not completely. It turns out that if I name my files `default.po` instead of `messages.po`... The page is mostly translated. Which is odd, because the way I understood it, the files have to be named the same as the domain you choose.

The website is mostly translated now. But it's still strange because there are a few strings here and there not being translated, despite their entries being correctly filled out.

Comment: Could be anything, starting from *"have you compiled to .mo?"* over encoding differences to some tool in the toolchain doing something wrong. You'll have to troubleshoot and provide some more details here.

Comment: I have no idea where to start. I have compiled it to .mo yes... it translates half my page. I use PHP with codeigniter, and I use POedit to compile the .mo files with. 
I also use a custom implementation in my php code to gain the ability to make comments and context entries. But when I check the po files, everything looks like its ok.

Comment: Also.. this is the method I use to implement commenting/context support on my site: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/gettext